# Powershell form text / textbox once invisible unable to make visible again

Tags: powershell, winforms, event-handling

How to make Text1 and Label1 reappear if Readme checkbox is deselected?
If checked on Readme Text1 and Label1 are made invisible. How to make visible again if Readme is subsequently unchecked? Currently its only one way

```bash
Clear-Host
[void][system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
        
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$objForm.Text          = 'Test'
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,300)
$objForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$CheckedListBox              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$CheckedListBox.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,20)
$CheckedListBox.size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(45,45) 
$CheckedListBox.CheckOnClick = $true 
$CheckedListBox.Items.AddRange(1..1)
$CheckedListBox.ClearSelected()


$CheckBox1              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox1.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,60)
$CheckBox1.size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,40)
$CheckBox1.Text         = "Readme"

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,100)
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label1.Text = 'Please enter Value in Minutes:'
$label1.Visible = $true

$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,120)
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,20)
$textBox1.Visible = $true

$CheckBox1.Add_Click({$label1.Visible = $false;$textBox1.Visible = $false })
$CheckBox1.Remove_Click({$label1.Visible = $true;$textBox1.Visible = $true})

$objForm.Controls.Add($CheckedListBox)
$objForm.Controls.Add($CheckBox1)
$objForm.Controls.Add($label1)
$objForm.Controls.Add($TextBox1)

$CheckedListBox.Add_Click({
    For ($i=1;$i -lt $CheckedListBox.Items.count;$i++) 
    {$CheckedListBox}
})


$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,220)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$objForm.AcceptButton = $okButton
$objForm.Controls.Add($okButton)

# put form in front of other windows
$objForm.TopMost = $True

# display the form
$DisplayForm     = $objForm.ShowDialog()

ForEach ($CheckedItem in $CheckedListBox.CheckedItems -join ',')
{
    Switch ($CheckedItem)
    {
        1       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        2       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        3       {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1,2}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1,3}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {2,3}   {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
        {1..3}  {"Checkbox $CheckedItem is checked";Break}
    }
}

if ($CheckBox1.Checked) {
    Write-Host "Readme is true"
} else {
    Write-Host "Readme is not true"
}

write-host $textBox1.Text.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.Click` event handler to:

```
# if there is a Click event on this CheckBox
$CheckBox1.Add_Click({
    # and this CheckBox is checked
    if ($this.Checked) {
        # hide these controls
        $label1.Visible = $textBox1.Visible = $false
        return
    }

    # else, show them
    $label1.Visible = $textBox1.Visible = $true
})
```

And remove this event handler, you're removing a handler that hasn't been added, so essentially this code isn't doing anything.

```bash
$CheckBox1.Remove_Click({
    $label1.Visible = $true
    $textBox1.Visible = $true
})
```

Comment: Thankyou for For quick response and assistance. Appears to be working as desired